# What is the default font of tpopumenu in delphi?

Tags: forms, delphi, fonts, vcl, popupmenu

I'm doing a program in Rad Studio XE2 which minimizes a trayicon.
I have found that the font of TPopMenu, and the ballon of TTrayicon depending on the operating system is completely different  (I have tried on windows 7 and windows xp).

I thought it could be the Application.DefaultFont, and edit it to start, but nothing. Are you aware that source gets?

```
procedure TForm_Principal.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Application.DefaultFont.Name := 'Tahoma';
end;
```

Comment: Do you want to know what the font is? Or do you want to be able to obtain it programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the font for menu items is taken from Screen.MenuFont.

Comment: I think this is basically right. It's perhaps a little more subtle. If menus are drawn by the VCL, then it uses `MenuFont`. However, many menus are drawn by the system. The system cannot see what is in the Delphi `MenuFont` object. However, `MenuFont` is initialised with `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` and so is initialised to the system menu font, the same as the system uses to paint menus.

Comment: I change the Screen.MenuFont and nothing happens,  Are you sure that is the Screen.MenuFont?

Comment: As David mentioned, the MenuFont is choosen for TPopupMenu when the VCL is drawing the menu and that this must not always be the case. Although, you should be save to get the current font for menus from that property, even if you are not able to set it for all popup menus.